# Error: soomla inApp purchase when click buy button

Tags: ios, xcode, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect, soomla

I am trying sandbox testing for my App but encounter an error when I click the buy button on an iOS device.

Here is my console output in Xcode:

> applicationWillResignActive() applicationDidBecomeActive()
>
> 2016-07-23 12:52:04.670 MyApp[2429:768800] [*** ERROR ***] SOOMLA
>   SoomlaStore:  An error occured for product id "com.myapp.coin20000"
>   with code "0"      and description "Error Domain=SKErrorDomain Code=0
>   "Cannot connect to iTunes Store"
>   UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Cannot connect to iTunes Store}"
>
> SOOMLA StoreEvents SOOMLA/UNITY OnUnexpectedStoreError
>
> UnityEngine.DebugLogHandler:LogFormat(LogType, Object, String,
>   Object[]) UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)
>   Soomla.SoomlaUtils:LogDebug(String, String)
>
> (Filename:
>   /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/artifacts/generated/common/runtime/UnityEngineDebugBindings.gen.cpp
>   Line: 37)

Please help me determine what to do to fix this error.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you running on a device or the simulator?  In app purchasing is not available on the simulator

Answer (score 0):

Oh! problem resolved.
Bundel identifire mismatch on itunestore and unity.